# How can I raise the bounty on my question?

Tags: support, bounties

I read that you can assign multiple bounties to a question, but I fail to see a way to do this. My question: [How to avoid already-authorized in Android Facebook SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495845/how-to-avoid-already-authorized-in-android-facebook-sdk)